# MySql Foreign key constraint and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, key, constraints

So I'm having trouble creating two databases called `role_perm` and `user_role`. I just couldn't find out where the problem is, since it shows me:

> Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

For both `role_perm` and `user_role`, there are five procedures that automatically creates my DBs, these codes are my MySQL codes...

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    ID INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `mobile` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `home` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `roles` (
    `role_id` INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `role_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `permissions` (
    `perm_id` INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `perm_desc` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`perm_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `role_perm` (
    `role_id` INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `perm_id` INT(8) NOT NULL,
    INDEX (`role_id`, `perm_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(role_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (perm_id) REFERENCES permissions(perm_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE  `user_role` (
    `user_id` INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `role_id` INT(8) NOT NULL,
    INDEX (`user_id`, `role_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users.ID,
    FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles.role_id
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: First of all you are mixing both primary key and foreign key. And also trying to increment automatically the foreign key. It is not possible to create primary key and give reference to other table.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve using the above tables

Comment: improved question syntax/readability

Comment: Yes, I want to create RBAC system for my website. here is the refrence:
http://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/

Comment: After 1 Day... can't find any answers! looked everywhere!